# Ember.js 2, transitionTo using multiple dynamic segments in first level route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, transition, ember-cli

I'm using Ember >= 2.13.x.

I need to use `transitionTo` from a route action to go in another route.

Here is the demo ember-twiddle: https://ember-twiddle.com/3cbb806f31f8d71a6c414452f4fc9ded

I have this situation:

*router.json*:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', {path: '/'});
  this.route('categories', {path: 'categories'});
  this.route('category', {path: ':category_id'});
  this.route('posts', {path: 'posts'});
  this.route('post', {path: ':category_id/:post_id'}); //I have multiple synamic segments in here
});
```

*routes/application.js*:

```
actions: {
    goToPost() {
        let post = this.store.findRecord('post', 1);
        this.transitionTo('post', post);
    }
}
```

*routes/post.js*:

```
model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('post', params.id);
},

serialize(model) {
    console.log('model in serialize():', model);
    return { category_id: model.get('category.id'), post_id: model.id };
}
```

*templates/application.hbs*:

```
<button type="button" {{action 'goToPost'}}>GoToPost with action (transitionTo)</button>
```

So when I click everything works as expected.

I fetch the model in application action and then I use `this.transitionTo('post', post);`.

In my `post` route then I have `serialize()` which, I read now, is using for URL composition when dynamic segments are present.

My question: **I'm using it the right way?**

Why I cannot use something like this: `this.transitionTo('post', post.category.id, post.id);` and let `model()` in `post` route fetch the model (from DB or store)?

I also tried to use `this.transitionTo('post', {category_id: post.category.id, post_id: post.id});` but obviously the `post` route `model()` doesn't load anything because it really thinks the object is already there.

So, I can fix this problem with `serialize()` method only. **Is it the right way?**

Comment: What do you have in your category route?

Comment: Is it  important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to override serialize hook, by default you will get the dynamic segments and queryParams in route model hook arguments.

```
model({post_id,category_id}) {
 return this.store.findRecord('post', post_id);
}
```

Here is the [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/6eb1163f93017184a120474945e2ffe3?openFiles=routes.post.js%2C&route=%2Fpost%2F1%2F2)

```
this.route('category', {path: 'category/:category_id'});
this.route('post', {path: 'post/:category_id/:post_id'});
```

I prefer to add corresponding prefix like `post` so that URL will become easily distinguisable.

If you want `transitionTo` to call model hook, then provide object or model in the argument always provide the required parameter may be string or number.
Refer: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments

Comment: In your twiddle you're using `this.transitionTo('post', 1,2)`. I use instead `this.transitionTo('post', post.get('category.id'), post.id)`. I don't know why but yesterday in my project it wasn't working. Thanks a lot.